# Django test.TestCase vs unittest.TestCase

Tags: django, unit-testing, testing

I am wondering a few things about best practices regarding supplying data for your tests.

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/testing/overview/)

```
from django.test import TestCase
from myapp.models import Animal

class AnimalTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        Animal.objects.create(name="lion", sound="roar")
        Animal.objects.create(name="cat", sound="meow")

    def test_animals_can_speak(self):
        """Animals that can speak are correctly identified"""
        lion = Animal.objects.get(name="lion")
        cat = Animal.objects.get(name="cat")
```

Like the example above I want to save a few models in the `setUp` method of the testcase which I later use in the particular testcases.
I could certainly provide a json fixture for this, but I rather create the models in the code for transparency this time since its very few.

When I use `django.test.TestCase` each individual test is running in a transaction according to the docs. But **no data** from my `setUp()` is present in the database. I ran it in a debugger and connect to the temp database and checked it.

When using `django.utils.unittest.TestCase` the data is present. Alas, the method is **aggregating the data** since its running for each individual test.

I understand why `unittest.TestCase` is aggregating the data due to not flushing the database. What I do not understand is why the data is not present when using `django.test.TestCase`. Even in the end of the `setUp()` method its still blank.

Is `django.test.TestCase` not supposed to save any data or am I doing something entirely wrong?

EDIT 1:
Did a clean project with this and it started working as I suspected it should. The `django.test.TestCase` filled the database with the data in the `setup()` method for each individual run so I guess theres have to be something quite fishy with the setup on my part. I´ll apply Occam's razor and see if I can find out what it is.

EDIT 2:
Cleaned out the models and tests files and ran the tests again. Setting the debugger to halt after the `setUp()` but theres still not anything in the database. The objects do have an `pk` and would assumably be saved to the database. Checked the `ModelState` object thats inherited to the `Model` and according to the `adding` attribute its saved to the database.

Added this debug code to the `setUp()` method:

```
from django.db import connections
    print connections.databases

{'default': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
'NAME': 'test_DATABASE_temp', 'TEST_CHARSET': None, 
'TEST_COLLATION': None, 'HOST': 'localhost', 'USER': 'user', 
'TEST_NAME': None, 'PASSWORD': 'password}
```

But when adding:

```
print Animals.objects.all().count()

2
```

I get the response that there are in fact objects available. But where are they? Getting a bit obsessed with this now I must admit =).

I can proceed now, but still lacking a satisfying answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django's `django.test.TestCase` does not commit the transaction, so it never appears in the database. The whole testcase is executed [inside a big](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/testing/overview/#django.test.TestCase) transaction, so that you can not check from outside what is happening to the database (since there is actually nothing at all happening to the database until the transaction is committed, which never happens)

Answer (score 1):

`django.test.TestCase` do a couple things for you, one of them being creating a test database (and destroying it once the test has completed). This is documented here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database

Comment: Yeah I plowed through that documentation as well. Didn´t get much wiser regarding the question though. I´ll set up a separate test in isolation.

Comment: @Gesias: I saw you edited your question. All I can say is that I never had such a problem with tests using setUp to populate the database. Perhaps something with transactions in your database settings ?

Comment: I have a lead I am working on. May come down to irregularities in the database on this machine. I´ll post back tomorrow with any solution I may find. Cheers for taking the time!